# Difference between "had + past" and "would have + past"?

Tags: tenses, modal-verbs, conditionals

Is there any difference between these two statements? When should each be used?

> - I thought you had slept.
> - I thought you would have slept.

Comment: Whoever down voted... please give feedback.

Comment: If you are an English language learner rather than a native speaker or serious linguist, you might find our sister-site for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com) to be a better fit for your questions than the current site, given that our charter here at ELU reads: “English Language & Usage Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for **linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts.”**

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a subtle difference.

"I thought you had slept" - You believed the person was sleeping.
"I thought you would have slept" - You believed that the person meant to sleep based on an unsaid condition.

In many situations these two could be used interchangeably.  The first implies very little about whether the person meant to sleep, just the belief that the person did sleep.  The second one is referring to the intent of the other person, making reference to their choice (intention/plan) based on the circumstances, condition or reason ("because" or "if" could be added to the sentence).

In reference to Susan's excellent link regarding "[would](http://www.butte.edu/departments/cas/tipsheets/grammar/would.html)":

> To show intention or plan:
>
> - She said she would come. = She said she was planning to come.

And I extrapolate:

> - I thought she would come. = I thought she was planning to come.
> - I thought she would sleep. = I thought she was planning to sleep.

Comment: sources are much appreciated in answers! Thanks. :-)

Comment: @susan Sorry, I used your reference (it was the best one out there) but used a different take on it.  I also removed what I said about emphasis.  I can imagine 2 ways of saying it depending on whether the condition was true or not, but couldn't put my finger on what it is.  And besides, that wasn't what the OP's question was anyway.